# Upload new files when .htaccess cach is set to one week?

Tags: .htaccess

I need to upload a new version of a CSS-file, but nothing happens. Then I discovered that the cach of CSS files was set to one week in the .htaccess file one the Apache server like this:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 week"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 week"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Is there a way to override this, so that the new CSS file can be used? I have tried to just remove this lines, but the old CSS files is still active on the site.

Comment: Use key parameter in your css file url so that will be treated as new and updated by apache and browser

Comment: @MuhammadZubairSaleem Do you mean that I should just rename it?

Comment: Yes, if you can else just add ?v=1.1 at the end of file

Comment: @MuhammadZubairSaleem Thanks for your help! But I still have problems! I just renamed the CSS file by adding a date, not like your suggestion, I guess it will still work? But now there there is no CSS file when I reload the site. Must be because the index.html is still the old one. I have changed the name of the CSS file in the index.html file. What can I do?

Comment: This thing must work as this is the proper way of doing this

Comment: And also index.html didn’t get cached

Comment: Yes, but isn't the index.html cached? ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 week" ??

Comment: Try adding date param at the end of html if works then add htacces rule to expire cached data at end user.

Comment: @MuhammadZubairSaleem Thanks for your help, but it's not working. It seems like the index.html file is loading the last version, but not the CSS file despite I have renamed it. I guess I have to change it all back and wait a week. Is there a way to turn off the chaching of all the files?

Answer (score 0):

For Disabling cache you can use this piece of code in your htaccess file

```
# DISABLE CACHING
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>
```

You will have more information over this [link](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/disable-caching-htaccess)

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but despite that I added your code to my .htaccess file, nothing happens. If I rename the CSS file, no CSS file is loaded at all. It vill only accept the first CSS file. But if I change the content in that CSS file, nothing happens. It seems that it only loading an old version of the CSS file. What can I do to remove all this cache thing and be able to upload files a see the result at once?